# Canvas disappearing on Chrome 49 on OS X, looks like a bug

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, canvas, charts, html5-canvas

**Edit**: Chrome just updated to 49.0.2623.108 and the issue has gone

---

I've come across some odd behaviour and have narrowed it down to Chrome 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit) on OS X El Capitan.

The angular chart (based on chart.js) is disappearing when focus is taken by an input field on returning to the Chrome window from elsewhere.

Please see [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/z4x9i8qqfjTOJDxihaG4).  (Issue is only apparent in windowed mode)

HTML is very simple:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Focus here" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-legend="true" chart-series="series">
      </canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Focus on the input field, slide to another desktop, slide back.  Canvas vanishes when focus is reclaimed by input field.

- Chrome Version 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit)
- Angular 1.4.4
- Chart.js 1.0.2
- Angular chart 0.9.0

I've tested Chrome 48, Safari, Firefox - none behave in this way.  I've submitted a Chrome bug report, however I seek validation from the good folk of Stack Overflow whether this is reproducible (I've seen it on both my Macbooks), and whether it is limited to Chrome 49 on  OS X or can be seen on other configurations?

Thanks
Ben

**Edit**:
Looks like others have seen this.  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198813/canvas-content-disappears-on-chrome-49-on-mac-with-an-angularjs-tooltip)

Comment: I can repro on same chrome version in osx10.9 If you're going to open an issue, it may be good to narrow down the problem a little bit (without the chart library, without the mouse events etc...)

Comment: Chrome just updated to 49.0.2623.108 and the issue has gone.